# dplyr mutate(): ignore values if group is NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm a newcommer to `dplyr` and have following question. My has `data.frame` one column serving as a grouping variable. Some rows *don't* belong to a group, the grouping column being `NA`.

I need to add some columns to the data.frame using the `dplyr` function `mutate`. I'd prefer that `dplyr` ignores all rows where the grouping column equals to `NA`.  I'll illustrate with an example:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2)

# Setting up some dummy data
df <- data.frame(
  Group = factor(c(rep("A",3),rep(NA,3),rep("B",5),rep(NA,2))),
  Value = abs(as.integer(rnorm(13)*10))
)

# Using mutate to calculate differences between values within the rows of a group
df <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Diff = Value-lead(Value))

df
# Source: local data frame [13 x 3]
# Groups: Group [3]
# 
#     Group Value  Diff
#    (fctr) (int) (int)
# 1       A     8     7
# 2       A     1   -14
# 3       A    15    NA
# 4      NA    11    11
# 5      NA     0    -1
# 6      NA     1    -8
# 7       B     7     5
# 8       B     2   -17
# 9       B    19    18
# 10      B     1    -3
# 11      B     4    NA
# 12     NA     9     6
# 13     NA     3    NA
```

Calculating the differences between rows without a group makes no sense and is corrupting the data. I need to remove these rows and have done so like this:

```
df$Diff[is.na(df$Group)]  <- NA
```

Is there a way to include the above command into the dplyr-chain using %>% ? Somewhere in the lines of:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Diff = Value-lead(Value)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Group))
```

But where the rows without a group are not removed all together? Or even better, is there a way to make `dplyr` ignore rows without a group?

There desired outcome would be:

```
# Source: local data frame [13 x 3]
# Groups: Group [3]
# 
#     Group Value  Diff
#    (fctr) (int) (int)
# 1       A     8     7
# 2       A     1   -14
# 3       A    15    NA
# 4      NA    11    NA
# 5      NA     0    NA
# 6      NA     1    NA
# 7       B     7     5
# 8       B     2   -17
# 9       B    19    18
# 10      B     1    -3
# 11      B     4    NA
# 12     NA     9    NA
# 13     NA     3    NA
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use an `iflelse` condition for the variable that you are trying to create:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(2)

df = data.frame(
  Group = factor(c(rep("A",3), rep(NA,3), rep("B",5), rep(NA,2))),
  Value = abs(as.integer(rnorm(13)*10))
) %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Diff = ifelse(is.na(Group), as.integer(NA), Value-lead(Value)))
```

Comment: Usual usage is `NA_integer_` a builtin constant, fyi.

Comment: @Frank Resolves to exactly the same thing: `identical(as.integer(NA), NA_integer_)` and I am not so sure about the "usual".

Comment: Fair enough. By "usual," I just mean the only way I've ever seen it done.